# Failed to install network-manager by dpkg without internet connection(Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop)

Tags: networking, network-manager, dpkg

My NetworkManager is broken so I do not have any internet connection. And I want to reinstall it. I got the package network-manager_1.22.10-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb and tried to install it by `sudo dpkg -i`, but an error occurred:(Chinese language)

```
(正在读取数据库 ... 系统当前共安装有 919338 个文件和目录。)
准备解压 network-manager_1.22.10-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 network-manager （1.22.10-1ubuntu1) 并覆盖 (1.22.10-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: 依赖关系问题使得 network-manager 的配置工作不能继续：
 network-manager 依赖于 libnm0 (= 1.22.10-1ubuntu1)；然而：
系统中 libnm0:amd64 的版本为 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2。

dpkg: 处理软件包 network-manager (--install)时出错：
 依赖关系问题 - 仍未被配置
正在处理用于 systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.7) 的触发器 ...
正在处理用于 dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) 的触发器 ...
正在处理用于 man-db (2.9.1-1) 的触发器 ...
在处理时有错误发生：
 network-manager
```

However, I cannot install the requested package libnm0 because the dependence is conflicted.
How do I revert my network connection?(I used `nmcli`, but it did not work)
Avaliable network device: wlp2s0

Comment: I found the answer in your output.

Answer (score 1):

Your output clearly states: `系统中 libnm0:amd64 的版本为 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2`

Your other Network Manager packages must match this version (1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2).

Instead, you downloaded `network-manager_1.22.10-1ubuntu1`. That's a lower version. See the difference?

The version of the `network-manager` package that you must download is NOT in the `focal` repository (`focal` = 1.22.10-1ubuntu1). You want the version in the `focal-updates` repository (`focal-updates` = 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.2)

Comment: But after that, Ubuntu Settings says “未找到 Wi-Fi 适配器”。

Comment: This is new information that should have been in your original question. It means that NetworkManager was probably not broken, and probably did not need to be reinstalled. I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: There are already many questions about what to do about that message -- use the Search box at the top of the page to see how to troubleshoot it, or ask a new question with complete information.